# Problem in the result after doing a select in the database

Tags: sql, actionscript-3, sqlite, air

I'm having a problem with the result obtained on a select in my sqlite.

I already have a database fed, and I'm doing queries in my application in adobe air. In my table I have 6 columns:

`id | name | email | CITY_ID | state_id | phone`

When I do a select of the entire table, it returns me an array of objects.

```
result[30].id = 30;
result [30]. name = John;
result [30]. email = john@xxx.com;
result [30]. city_id = 1352;
result [30]. state_id = 352;
result [30]. phone = xxxxxxxxx;
```

All information came right, but the id value is incorrect ( correct is not 30 ) . It seems to me that i'm getting the numerical order and not getting the id column value.

Has anyone had this problem?

*UPDATE*

My query is:

```
_selectStat = new SQLStatement();
_selectStat.addEventListener( SQLEvent.RESULT, onDataLoaded );
_selectStat.addEventListener( SQLErrorEvent.ERROR, onSqlError );
_selectStat.sqlConnection = _connection;

var sql:String = 'SELECT * FROM "main"."agencia"';

_selectStat.text = sql;
_selectStat.execute();
```

Comment: Hy locrizak, I updated with the query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Adobe development or sqlite, so I'm speculating here.  If 'id' is a database property, then you may need to indicate that you want the column 'id', and not the property 'id'.  There should be a way to do this with the adobe application syntax or the sqlite SQL syntax.  In mssql, brackets [] are used for this, so it would be [id] to indicate the column 'id' and not the property.  There should be something similar for your environment.

Comment: The name, email, city_id ... are also columns, and that values are coming correct. I think this is not the problem.